# Does a 'Two block - spring ' system execute SHM under a permanent force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

When the following system is run , do the two masses execute oscillations while they are in motion , the kind we get when No permanent force is being applied like the one in this case , but a temporary force is applied in place and then withdrawn , surely the two masses perform SHM then. 
 [image]

Comment: Yes, SHM plus translation at constant speed.

Comment: not constant speed , there is a force in action , isn't it?

Comment: What about the part "and then withdrawn"?

Comment: If you want to consider the period during which there is an exerted force, look up vertical SHM.

Comment: But the spring is fixed there.I will put my solution.

Comment: "then withdrawn was the other case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90203/discussion-between-stafusa-and-aditya-prakash).